# server.xml and tomcat-users.xml file location in amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I need to to update the `tomcat-users.xml` in my elastic beanstalk instance in order for my form based authentication to work. I was able to connect to the elastic beanstalk AMI directory using SSH. However, even after all the searching I could not locate the tomcat-users.xml file. On my localhost it's under the 'Servers' folder. I would appreciate if you  could tell me the location of the file and if I can modify it through the SSH.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to find out the path if you can issue the command `ps -ef | grep tomcat`. If I am correct it should be in location `/usr/share/tomcat`

Answer (score 1):

not yet tested, but I have found this article:

http://www.michaelwilliams.co.za/amazon-ec2-elastic-beanstalk-basic-authentication/

It indicates the following:

> Normally you would edit the tomcat-users.xml file in the Tomcat conf
>   directory. Instead we’ll create a users.xml file in the web
>   application WEB-INF directory. This file contains the credentials of
>   the users who will be given access to the updates directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="netbeans-application"/>
    <user username="user1" password="password" roles="netbeans-application"/>
    <user username="user2" password="password" roles="netbeans-application"/>
    <user username="user3" password="password" roles="netbeans-application"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

> Your application is not looking for the user
>   credential information in users.xml by default. To show your
>   application where to find the user information create the file
>   context.xml in the META-INF directory of your web application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/EC2Example">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" pathname="/opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/users.xml"/>
</Context>
```